# Windows 10 boot - The header checksum for this file doesn't match the computed checksum

Tags: windows-10, boot, uefi

I have a laptop from a customer with a very familiar problem.

This annoying issue has plagued me for years, and all I have done in the past is a wipe and reinstall, then restoring the users folder and contents.

The owner has no backups, so understands it may be reinstalled, but this laptop has a lot of software which will require a lot of time to reinstall. I am trying to avoid this.

It isn't a hardware issue, and machine works fine after wipe and reinstall.

What is the file it refers to? \windows\system32\winload.efi and error code 0xc0000221 are mentioned.

The Windows 10 version is 21h1 and I have this version on USB, and hiren USB utility.

The problem is part of the exceptionally undocumented 'Windows boot issues' which has been a stable part of windows boot issues going back to XP, so I am going to remove the hidden system partition and recreate the boot on the main C drive - thus hopefully repairing the checksum for winload.

Has anyone any experience of this unusual issue?

Comment: Please see if this helps you.   ...............   https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/error-0xc0000221-winloadexe/9bdda5d4-d02d-4476-bd6f-893e601f6f82

Comment: If you can boot into Safe mode or Command Prompt mode, try running `sfc /scannow`.

Comment: Got slightly further, now I have error 0xc0000242 sgrmagent.sys - missing or contains errors. I got past winload.efi error by replacing the old 0 byte file. This is akin to black magic and guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this - not simple to do. took ages.  Hiren USB boot essential.

image source to two ssds **cloned.** one to play with and one backup

Plug one backup into another computer - use shadow copy explorer to extract c:\windows\system32\drivers#*.* to replace later.

wipe & reinstall with win 10 home edition with same revision iso from source.
once at the final stage of setup, at first prompt hit shift f10. shutdown /f /s /t 0.

clone C partition from backup onto C partition of reinstalled clean image.

reboot into hiren - sfc /scannow - at least 5 times.

i may of had an odd write error, but i had to replace all of the files in the root of drivers.

set using bcdedit safemode. Reboot.

wait. it appears to sort an update out - this took far longer than I would of expected.

Into safe mode. Now it's just a case of finding the driver or service that has caused this.